# from pytrends.pyGTrends import pyGTrendsnot working

Tags: python, google-trends

I installed pytrends using this wheel file [pytrends.whl](https://pypi.python.org/packages/b5/b9/1942e2b6cfa643212d5d856793ae9584d635be2f536e94983fb74496ab5b/pytrends-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl) and the below directories

```
 Directory of C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pytrends

09/15/2016  10:30 AM    <DIR>          .
09/15/2016  10:30 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/15/2016  10:30 AM             6,799 request.py
09/15/2016  10:30 AM                 0 __init__.py
09/15/2016  10:30 AM    <DIR>          __pycache__
               2 File(s)          6,799 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  323,016,486,912 bytes free
```

and

```
 Directory of C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pytrends-3.1.0.dist-info

09/15/2016  10:30 AM    <DIR>          .
09/15/2016  10:30 AM    <DIR>          ..
09/15/2016  10:30 AM             7,900 DESCRIPTION.rst
09/15/2016  10:30 AM                 4 INSTALLER
09/15/2016  10:30 AM             8,622 METADATA
09/15/2016  10:30 AM               878 metadata.json
09/15/2016  10:30 AM               835 RECORD
09/15/2016  10:30 AM                 9 top_level.txt
09/15/2016  10:30 AM               116 WHEEL
               7 File(s)         18,364 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  323,017,011,200 bytes free
```

And from here, unlike in any packages where the submodules the are imported are inside the package folder, This one basically contains no sumodules. It might be the way i installled the package. 
This ome liner ,

```
from pytrends.pyGTrends import pyGTrends
```

gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GoogleTrend.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pytrends.pyGTrends import pyGTrends
ImportError: No module named 'pytrends.pyGTrends'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Or is it better to use `gtrends` module instead? i am using `python 3.5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use `from pytrends.request import TrendReq`.

See [example.py](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/blob/master/examples/example.py).

Comment: I missed that part. Thanks a lot.